# Why does Excel's now() function returns different times depending on device/browser used?

Tags: microsoft-excel, time

I am using the current time to run 'live' calculations in Excel using `=NOW()`.  The Excel file is saved in my OneDrive.  When I embed my Excel worksheet on a web page sometimes it displays the local (system) time and sometimes it displays UTC time.  It appears to depend on the device or browser being used.  If I access the web site from my windows computer the time is displayed as system time.  If I view it from my iPhone or my Mac computer it shows UTC time.  Is there a way to force it to use UTC time (preferred), or force it to use the local system time? Either one will work but needs to be consistent for my calculations to be correct?  As this is embedded there can't be links to external sites or macros.  Also I'll mention I don't care which time zone the user is in as long as the time is handled the same by all.  I've created a blog post to show this issue.

https://currentawarenessnaples.blogspot.com/2023/09/blog-post_25.html

I'm using the iframe code that Excel generates to embed it.

Comment: It’s a rounding issue, “mmmm d, yyyy h:mm” should be “mmmm d, yyyy h:mm:ss”. Likewise if you want UTC always, you have to specify, a timezone otherwise excel will use the systems preferences

Comment: So I live in florida and I am 4 hours behind UTC.  If i go to this site on my pc the time shows my current time.  If i go to the site on my iphone it shows UTC time (4 hours ahead of me).  When i run my calculations they will be different on my pc than my phone due to these 4 hours.

Comment: Here is a good video on how to embed excel on a webpage.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ViZ7aOxF3I

Comment: You could add to your worksheet a means for overriding the NOW value if it's incorrect, or add a cell for the time-offset in hours with a default value.

Comment: Yea the problem is I dont' know when the NOW() value will be UTC or Local TIme.  As long as its ALWAYS one or the other i can work with it.

Answer (score 0):

This code works with Excel 365 VBA

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub sbTest()
 MsgBox GetUTCTime()
End Sub

Public Function GetUTCTime() As Date

' https://599cd.com/blog/display-article.asp?ID=1398

    Dim XMLHTTP As Object
    Dim ResponseText As String
    Dim MyURL As String
    Dim L As Long, S As String
    
    MyURL = "http://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip.txt"
    Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    XMLHTTP.Open "GET", MyURL, False
    XMLHTTP.send
    ResponseText = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
    ResponseText = Replace(ResponseText, Chr(10), vbNewLine)
    Set XMLHTTP = Nothing
    
    S = ResponseText
    L = InStr(S, "utc_datetime:")
    S = Right(S, Len(S) - L + 1)
    S = Left(S, 33)
    S = Mid(S, 20, 2) & "/" & Mid(S, 23, 2) & "/" & Mid(S, 15, 4) & " " & Right(S, 8)

    GetUTCTime = CDate(S)
    
End Function
```